# PHP converting my floats to integers in my array

Tags: php, arrays, integer, rounding

I have this code:

```
  $val = (float) $desc;
  if (!isset($runepage['statistics'][$key])) {
        $runepage['statistics'][$key] = (float) 0.0;
  }
  $runepage['statistics'][$key] += $val;
```

where `$val` is a float.

But when I print out the array at the end all the values end up as integers. For example, if there were 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 for the same `$key`, it would print out 3 rather than 4.5.

I'm not sure why it's doing this.

Edit: here's the output of the array

```
[statistics] => Array
    (
        [magic penetration] => 9
        [ability power per level] => 9
        [movement speed] => 3
        [magic resist] => 9
    )
```

Comment: Show us the code that does the printing

Comment: I can't see any integer casting going on there. Would you add in how you are printing the array?

Comment: You don't have to do `(float) 0.0` by the way - a zero here will suffice, and it will still be treated as float.

Comment: I'm printing it with print_r($runepage) and I tried var_export as well. Yeah, I didn't put (float) 0.0 initially, I just started fiddling with it to see if it would change anything - it didn't.

Comment: Ah, see @porneL's answer. Perhaps you could use a string prefix to get this to work, i.e. turn your numerically indexed array into a hash? So, keys could be `key_3.5` rather than `3.5`.

Comment: The keys are already a string. It's the value portion that's being trimmed to an integer.

Comment: OK, I was right first time! I'm still not seeing how your array is output - more code please `:)`.

Comment: (Don't forget to address using @halfer, otherwise people generally don't get notified. You do however automatically, as it's your question).

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I misread your question assuming the `$key` was a float.

In case of `$val` — I don't know. It should work fine for values, so source of the problem may be elsewhere. In PHP it's safe to add integers and floats together and the result will be float.

---

If the `$key` was a float:

That's normal, [documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) behavior. Arrays are not supposed to be indexed by floats.

Also numeric-looking strings are cast to integers too. `$a[5] === $a['5']`.

Unfortunately PHP arrays are not a generic key-value store. Your best bet is serializing keys to a string that does not start with a digit.

Comment: he never said that $key vas float

Comment: @Acuao - he quite explicitly does say that in the penultimate paragraph of his question: `But when I print out the array at the end all the keys end up as integers`

Comment: It's the $val that's a float, the key is a string. I've added the output of the array to the initial post.

Comment: yes sure i know, you was saying that if for a key the value was 1.5 (x3) its print 3 instead of 4.5? - @mark-baker i'm not an english pro, but you're totaly wrong